# client app specifications making backend calls (HTTP REST)

Tags: rest, http

We have a scenario, where when the end user login into our mobile apps (these apps can be any 3rd party); we expect the app to make a call to backend services (built using HTTP REST) every 30 seconds.

But because of the various releases and bugs got introduced on mobile apps; some times we see the spike more than expected.

My question is are there any open specifications available for clients (in this case mobile apps) to send some additional information on why they are making more no.of calls than expected ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a general solution to this. There is a standard response for a server to tell the client that they are sending too many requests (429) but it sounds like that's not what you're after.

Comment: 429 is one option from server; I want to make server more intelligent before sending 429 by providing the reason code from client.

Comment: A server can't really know the 'reason' unless that reason was sent by the client.